# XML XElement c#

Tags: c#, xml

Deseo ejecutar varias veces este codigo :

```
            new XElement("detalles",



       for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
        {


            ////********************* PRODUCTO *******************************************
            new XElement("detalle",
            new XElement("codigoPrincipal", "*****"),
                             new XElement("codigoAuxiliar", "*****"),
                             new XElement("descripcion", "*****"),
                             new XElement("cantidad", "*****"),
                             new XElement("precioUnitario", "*****"),
                             new XElement("descuento", "*****"),
                             new XElement("precioTotalSinImpuesto", "*****"),



        new XElement("impuestos",
            new XElement("impuesto",
                             new XElement("codigo", "*****"),
                             new XElement("codigoPorcentaje", "*****"),
                             new XElement("tarifa", "*****"),
                             new XElement("baseImponible", "*****"),
                             new XElement("valor", "*****")

                             )
                             )
                             )



        }
              ////**********************************************************************
```

lo quiero repetir varias veces atraves de un bucle for(dinamicamente), pero me da un error de sintaxis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la primera línea debes cerrar el paréntesis ) y en las últimas líneas deberían ser solo dos paréntesis.

Comment: No funciono Eric

Comment: Agrega todo el codigo de tu funcion no se ve a quien asignas el valor final

Comment: el codigo debe ir como texto. no podes poner un for ahi... porque querrias hacer eso?

Comment: despues de new XElement("detalles", objeto) , se refiere a la creacion de otro xml elemento no puedes agregar un for para que se llene como si fuese lista.

Answer (score 1):

```
new XElement("detalle"); //Y este otro

            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            {           
                new XElement("detalle",
                new XElement("codigoPrincipal", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("codigoAuxiliar", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("descripcion", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("cantidad", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("precioUnitario", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("descuento", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("precioTotalSinImpuesto", "*****"),

            new XElement("impuestos",
                new XElement("impuesto",
                                 new XElement("codigo", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("codigoPorcentaje", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("tarifa", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("baseImponible", "*****"),
                                 new XElement("valor", "*****")

                                 )
                                 )
                                 ); //Faltaria este
            }
```

Te faltaría el punto y como en ambas sentencias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo crea el nodo raiz y agrega sus elementos con el metodo **Add**, esta es la solucion:

```
XElement nodoDetalles = new XElement("Detalles");    

            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            {
                nodoDetalles.Add(new XElement("detalle",
                  new XElement("codigoPrincipal", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("codigoAuxiliar", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("descripcion", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("cantidad", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("precioUnitario", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("descuento", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("precioTotalSinImpuesto", "*****"),

              new XElement("impuestos",
                  new XElement("impuesto",
                                   new XElement("codigo", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("codigoPorcentaje", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("tarifa", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("baseImponible", "*****"),
                                   new XElement("valor", "*****")

                                   )
                                   ))
              );
```

---

Para un for de 3 Elementos esta es la salida:

```
<Detalles>
  <detalle>
    <codigoPrincipal>*****</codigoPrincipal>
    <codigoAuxiliar>*****</codigoAuxiliar>
    <descripcion>*****</descripcion>
    <cantidad>*****</cantidad>
    <precioUnitario>*****</precioUnitario>
    <descuento>*****</descuento>
    <precioTotalSinImpuesto>*****</precioTotalSinImpuesto>
    <impuestos>
      <impuesto>
        <codigo>*****</codigo>
        <codigoPorcentaje>*****</codigoPorcentaje>
        <tarifa>*****</tarifa>
        <baseImponible>*****</baseImponible>
        <valor>*****</valor>
      </impuesto>
    </impuestos>
  </detalle>
  <detalle>
    <codigoPrincipal>*****</codigoPrincipal>
    <codigoAuxiliar>*****</codigoAuxiliar>
    <descripcion>*****</descripcion>
    <cantidad>*****</cantidad>
    <precioUnitario>*****</precioUnitario>
    <descuento>*****</descuento>
    <precioTotalSinImpuesto>*****</precioTotalSinImpuesto>
    <impuestos>
      <impuesto>
        <codigo>*****</codigo>
        <codigoPorcentaje>*****</codigoPorcentaje>
        <tarifa>*****</tarifa>
        <baseImponible>*****</baseImponible>
        <valor>*****</valor>
      </impuesto>
    </impuestos>
  </detalle>
  <detalle>
    <codigoPrincipal>*****</codigoPrincipal>
    <codigoAuxiliar>*****</codigoAuxiliar>
    <descripcion>*****</descripcion>
    <cantidad>*****</cantidad>
    <precioUnitario>*****</precioUnitario>
    <descuento>*****</descuento>
    <precioTotalSinImpuesto>*****</precioTotalSinImpuesto>
    <impuestos>
      <impuesto>
        <codigo>*****</codigo>
        <codigoPorcentaje>*****</codigoPorcentaje>
        <tarifa>*****</tarifa>
        <baseImponible>*****</baseImponible>
        <valor>*****</valor>
      </impuesto>
    </impuestos>
  </detalle>
</Detalles>
```